# Alter table set Identity column

Tags: sybase

I have a sybase table ("Test") having the following columns:

```
MyIdentity numberic(9,0)
Name
User
```

The table is filled with lots of records. I want to alter MyIdentity column to be an identity.

There are currently no duplicate values for MyIdentity in the table. How can i alter the table and set MyIdentity as identity?

Comment: Good question. I thought I knew the answer, but not in Sybase...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't, something like

```
Create a new Table called test2 with the identity set up

Then

Set Identity_Insert Test2 On

Insert Test2 Select * From Test

Set Identity_Insert Test2 Off

Drop Test and Rename Test 2...
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on my version (Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3) the following seems to do the trick (syntactic sugar omitted):

Add a new identity column:

```
alter table Test add newMyIdentity numeric(9,0) identity not null
```

Prepare for updates:

```
set identity_insert Test on
set identity_update Test on
```

Copy the existing ID (to be able to preserve foreign keys etc):

```
update Test set newMyIdentity=MyIdentity
```

Drop the old definition, rename the newly created column:

```
alter table Test drop MyIdentity
sp_rename "Test.newMyIdentity", MyIdentity
```

Clean up:

```
set identity_insert Test off
set identity_update Test off
sp_recompile Test
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
create index MyIdentity on Test
```

See [http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/36137;pt=36137](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/36137;pt=36137;lang=nl?DwebQuery=set%20indentity#X).

Comment: That's not going to do it. No identity column still, just a unique constraint.